# Get sinon to resolve a promise when stubbed function is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I have a set of integration tests for message queueing code (over a real RabbitMQ). The tests are verifying that the correct use case is triggered when a specific message arrives.

```js
it("should trigger the use case", () => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(app, 'useCaseToTrigger').resolves();
  await publishMessage({ id: "SOME_ID" })
  // FAIL - Message isn't processed yet.
  stub.should.have.been.calledWith(match({id: "SOME_ID" }))
})
```

This doesn't work. The `await` statement waits for the message to be published, but says nothing of when the message is processed.

I can add a delay, but that quickly becomes a huge waste of time (if there are multiple tests).

```js
it("should trigger the use case", () => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(app, 'useCaseToTrigger').resolves();
  await publishMessage({ id: "SOME_ID" })
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
  // PASS - the message has been processed before the verification
  stub.should.have.been.calledWith(match({id: "SOME_ID" }))
})
```

But if I make the stubbed function resolve a promise when called, I can get my test to work without any undue delay.

```js
it("should trigger the use case", () => {
  const promise = new Promise(r => {
    sinon.stub(app, "useCaseToTrigger").callsFake(() => {
      setImmediate(() => { r(); }) // Push to the end of the event loop
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
  })
  await publishMessage({ id: "SOME_ID" })
  await promise;
  // PASS - Message processed before continuing test
  app.useCaseToTrigger.should.have.been.calledWith(match({id: "SOME_ID" }))
})
```

This does become a bit cumbersome to deal with (and probably not the easiest to read either). But it also gives eslint floating promises warnings. So to avoid those warnings, I need to rewrite it to:

```js
it("should trigger the use case", () => {
  await Promise.all([
    new Promise(r => {
      sinon.stub(app, "useCaseToTrigger").callsFake(() => {
        setImmediate(() => { r(); }) // Push to the end of the event loop
        return Promise.resolve();
      })
    }),
    publishMessage({ id: "SOME_ID" })
  ]);
  // PASS - Message processed before continuing test
  app.useCaseToTrigger.should.have.been.calledWith(match({id: "SOME_ID" }))
})
```

Is there a way to make this cleaner.

Comment: "*The `await` statement waits for the message to be published, but says nothing of when the message is processed.*" - why not? Doesn't `publishMessage` call `app.useCaseToTrigger`? Or does it not wait for it?

Comment: @Bergi because it's an integration test over a real RabbitMQ. And the publisher has no knowledge of if the message has been processed by a consumer.

Comment: Ah, so it's more about receiving an event. The return value of `useCaseToTrigger` doesn't really matter, and if the functionality is broken (`useCaseToTrigger` is not getting called) the test will need to time out instead of immediately throwing.

Comment: I don't see the reason for "*Push to the end of the event loop*". You can probably simplify to just `new Promise(resolve => { sinon.stub(app, "useCaseToTrigger").callsFake(resolve); })`

Comment: @Bergi the return value of `useCaseToTrigger` does matter (does it resolve or reject). If it resolves, the message should be acknowledged so it doesn't get processed again. If it rejects, the behavior should depend on the type of error. If the error is something transient, like a broken database connection, or downstream 500 HTTP status codes, we should just retry with an exponential backoff. But if the message itself is invalid, it should be dead-lettered immediately. Push to the end of event loop is not necessary for this particular test, but could be verifying the error cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use an empty promise to await, so the app logic eventually resolves that promise when it is called. Sinon provides a [promise fake](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v14/promises/) that makes this a bit easier than creating a `new Promise` with an external reference to the `resolve` function.

```
const p = sinon.promise()
const stub = sinon.stub(app, 'useCaseToTrigger').callsFake(p.resolve)
await publishMessage({ id: "SOME_ID" })
await p
sinon.assert.calledWith(stub, { id: "SOME_ID" })
```

It looks like sinon `.resolves()` uses `Promise.resolve` at the time of the stub call, so it doesn't have a reference to the eventual promise at stub creation, otherwise a `stub.promise` type of reference might have been useful here to avoid the additional promise setup.